# How to get the same results using "fGARCH" and "rugarch" packages?

Tags: r, garch

I'm trying to get the same GARCH (1,1) on both `fGARCH` and `rugarch` packages but the 'sigma' series I get from both seems to be very different. The code I use is below. How can I set up rugarch to be exactly like fGARCH?

fGARCH:

```
model2=garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = x, trace=FALSE)
sigma2=as.matrix(model2@sigma.t)
```

rugarch:

```
spec2 = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", 
                                        garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                        submodel = "GARCH", 
                                        external.regressors = NULL, 
                                        variance.targeting = FALSE), 

   mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), 
                external.regressors = NULL), 
                distribution.model = "norm", 
                start.pars = list(), 
                fixed.pars = list())

garch2 = ugarchfit(spec = spec2, data = x, solver='hybrid')

fit_garch2=as.matrix(sigma(garch2))
```

EDIT: Sorry for not being so clear on the first time. Just to clarify the problem: I am using a data set (real data from a index return) that gives me relevant different outputs using each package. fGARCH gives me a much more relevant ALPHA1 than rugarch do. rugarch gives me basically white noise as a result. That difference is enough to have relevant differences on each output as you can see below. The question is how can I set rugarch's solver to get to the same optimization used by fGARCH?

fGARCH:

```
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)  
mu     3.879e-06   3.912e-04    0.010   0.9921    
omega  4.793e-06   2.051e-06    2.338   0.0194 *  
alpha1 5.176e-02   1.174e-02    4.408 1.04e-05 ***
beta1  9.266e-01   1.729e-02   53.597  < 2e-16 ***
```

rugarch:

```
    Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu     -0.000173    0.000422   -0.40944 0.682214
omega   0.000000    0.000001    0.53499 0.592654
alpha1  0.001305    0.000470    2.77881 0.005456
beta1   0.996620    0.000289 3449.29767 0.000000
```

Outputs for both packages using real data:

```
> print(head(model2@sigma.t))

[1] 0.01474911 0.01447529 0.01442744 0.01416295 0.01386903 0.01376466

> print(head(garch2@fit$sigma))

[1] 0.01474511 0.01473423 0.01472338 0.01471256 0.01470177 0.01471629
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you also include the summary of fitted models (their coefficients and standard errors)?

Comment: You might be better on a programming site if you get no response here as this seems to bridge the gap between a statistical question and a programming one.

Comment: This is mostly about reading the package documentation carefully and examining the model output, which I again suggest to include.

Comment: R1989, does that answer your question? If so, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. If not, let us know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting virtually the same results from the two pieces of code you are comparing on simulated data. Here is an example:

```
library(fGarch)
library(rugarch)

# Specify ARMA(0,0)-GARCH(1,1) with particular parameter values as the data generating process
spec1=ugarchspec(mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)),fixed.pars=list(mu=0.1,omega=0.01,alpha1=0.1,beta1=0.8))
# Generate one realization of length 1000
set.seed(1); x=ugarchpath(spec=spec1,n.sim=1000)@path$seriesSim
# Fit a model using "fGarch"
model2=garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = x, trace=FALSE)
print(model2)
# Specify a model using "rugarch"
spec2 = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), submodel = "GARCH", external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
                   mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = NULL), distribution.model = "norm", start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list())
# Fit the model using "rugarch"
garch2 = ugarchfit(spec = spec2, data = x, solver='hybrid')
# Compare model coefficients
print(coef(model2))
print(coef(garch2))
# Compare fitted standard deviations
print(head(model2@sigma.t))
print(head(garch2@fit$sigma))
> head(model2@sigma.t)
[1] 0.3027147 0.2902284 0.2873441 0.2834843 0.2813985 0.3233465
> head(garch2@fit$sigma)
[1] 0.3026084 0.2901918 0.2873556 0.2835204 0.2814490 0.3234529
```

As you can see, the values are equal up to the third (or the fourth) digit.